# Return struct array from function c++

Tags: c++, arrays, function, struct

i am trying pass a struct array  from a function. i searched a lot but was unable to find a way to this. below is the code i am tring.

```
struct menuItemType
{
    int itemNo;
    string menuItem;
    double price;
};

void getData(menuItemType *menuList[10])
{
    menuList[0]->itemNo = 111;  
    menuList[0]->menuItem = "Apple";    
    menuList[0]->price = 2.00;

    ....
    menuList[0]->itemNo = 120;  
    menuList[0]->menuItem = "Chocolate";    
    menuList[0]->price = 5.00;
}

int main()
{
    /* i know that i can't return a array. but i want to get the menuList[10] values here. 
    not sure which code i have to use..*/
}
```

Comment: sorry typing issue. i mean int main(){}

Comment: [std::array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) is a thin wrapper around arrays that *can* be returned from functions.

Comment: "i know that i can't return a array" erm.. no you can return (almost) anything, unless the function is declared `void` ;)

Comment: @tobi303 You can't declare function to return C-style array in C++ (it can return pointer, actually).

Comment: @Zereges no you cant. But Who needs that If you can return a `std::array` or some Custom wrapper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `void getData(menuItemType *menuList[10])` does not return anything. Instead, it fills the data in the memory pointed by input parameter.

```
int main()
{
    menuItemType data[10];
    getData(&data);
    std::cout << data[9].menuItem << std::endl; // Chocolate
}
```

However, why are you insisting on using low level arrays? Use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead.

```
std::vector<menuItemType> getData()
{
    std::vector<menuItemType> data;
    data.push_back({111, "Apple", 2.00});
    ...
    data.push_back({120, "Chocolate", 5.00});
    return std::move(data);
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<menuItemType> data = getData();
    std::cout << data[9].menuItem << std::endl; // Chocolate
}
```

It will print `Chocolate`, because I assume there is a typo in your code.

Comment: You could also use a std::map<int, menuItemType> if you wanted to actually index by itemNo (presumably factoring itemNo out of the struct).

Or you could use boost::multi_index if you wanted to get ambitious, which would allow you to index by more than one attribute (hashed by itemNo, ordered by price, etc)

Comment: But this was not OP asked for. That should go to [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: thank you for the help, but this gets compile errors:                main.cpp:17:20: warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11
     data.push_back({111, "Apple", 2.00});
main.cpp:19:12: error: 'move' is not a member of 'std'
     return std::move(data);
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:25:18: error: too many arguments to function 'std::vector<menuItemType> getData()'
     getData(&data);
                  ^
main.cpp:14:27: note: declared here
 std::vector<menuItemType> getData()